# Lag in blazor application while using statehaschanged() and while loop inside async function

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I have a blazor index page where all action is happening. When index starts it creates `_mGame` object. Inside this object's class(`GameManager`) I have an infinite loop which keeps program running. At some point in the program I run a function from that initially created object with button:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" @onclick="e => _gameM.StartGame()">Start</button>
```

The problem is:
**The more I click this button the more app starts to lag.**

Whole code in index:

```
@code { 
    GameManager _gameM;
    public string message { get; set; } = "";
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _gameM = new GameManager();
        _gameM.MainLoopCompleted += (e, o) => StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Also the most important methods from `_mGame` class are below -the more it runs `_gameM.StartGame();` the more it starts to lag, and I thinking maybe `_gameM.StartGame();`  is creating something multiple times like maybe `Mainloop();`, but so far it is just guessing and I cannot find the fix.

```
public void StartGame()
        {
            _mainSquare = new MainSquare();
            _otherSquares = new List<OtherSquares>();
            _colorSquare = new SqrBoard();
            _monsterClass = new MonsterClass();
            firstlist = new List<OtherSquares>();
            message = "";
            AddSquares(); // just ads some stuff to _otherSquares.Add..
            MainLoop();
        }
        public async void MainLoop()
        {
            IsRunning = true;
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                SomeLoop();
                CalculateSquares();
                MonsterAction();
                MainLoopCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                await Task.Delay(20);
                GameOver();   
            }
        }
```

To sum up it seems:

1. `_gameM.MainLoopCompleted += (e, o) => StateHasChanged();` line from index keeps updating changes (I am not sure fully how it works)
2. After each time I run `_mGame.StartGame();`it starts `MainLoop();`
3. `MainLoop` has infinite `while`.

So am I creating multiple infinite while loops on each button click? If yes, how can I remove one loop and create a new one on the button click?

Comment: I may be reading this code wrong, but it looks like MainLoop loops every 20+ millsecs (20millsecs + the time it takes to run the other code in the loop).  Every loop it invokes MainLoopCompleted which fires StateHasChanged ever 20 millseconds.  In other words your updating the UI every 20 or so millsecs.  This ain't the way it's designed to be used.  Make you app event driven.  Only update the UI when there's something to update.  Only fire MainLoopCompleted when the loop detects something has happened.

Comment: WASM or server-side? I guess Server Side. I would make `MainLoopCompleted` a `Func<Task>` and add  `async() => {await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);}`

Comment: @ShaunCurtis well, update loops actually work quite nice: [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTmZCu16LNU) (3 part series)

Comment: Ok stand corrected

Comment: @JHBonarius it is WASM